# Обработка ошибки когда пользователь загрузил больше изображений чем положено

Tags: node.js

Как реализовать обработку ошибки когда пользователь загрузил больше изображений чем положено?

```
let upload = upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }])
app.post('/profile', upload , function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files - объект (String -> Array), где fieldname - ключ, и значение - массив файлов
  //
  // например:
  //  req.files['avatar'][0] -> File
  //  req.files['gallery'] -> Array
})
```

Например в `avatar` положил два фото в место одного или в `gallery` десять в место положенных 8, то выдает ошибку:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Projects\backend\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Busboy.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\Projects\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at PartStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
    at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:182:13)
```

Как ее обработать чтобы на пример было так:

```
        return res.status(401).json({
            failed: 'Loading more than one photo'
        });
```

Или для `gallery`

```
        return res.status(401).json({
            failed: 'More photo upload'
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
   upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
          //Тут проверяете количество переданных изображений и возвращаете ошибку
          return res.status(401).json({
             failed: 'Loading more than one photo'
          });
      } else if (err) {
          // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
      }
      // Everything went fine.
   })
})
```

Comment: Не получается, если убираешь `upload`, после `'/profile',` выдает ошибку, что не видит его

Comment: `let upload` замените на `var upload`